SharePoint Hybrid Search - search only works with Site Collection and not with fileshare
We are looking to expand our search capabilities in SharePoint Online to include documents stored on a file share. To achieve this, we set up a new server with on-premises SharePoint Subscription Edition and configured Hybrid Search.
We followed the Microsoft Documentation (Configure cloud hybrid search roadmap) and used the basic architecture. Instead of using the Hybrid Configuration Wizard, we generated the Cloud Search Service Application and onboarded it using PowerShell scripts provided by Microsoft.
We did not encounter any errors, and everything seemed to be configured correctly. After the setup, we crawled a small batch of documents from the file share to test if we could search for them in SharePoint Online. Unfortunately, the search did not return any results (we used the isexternalcontent:1 command).
The default content access account for the Cloud Hybrid Search Service Application has permissions on the files in the FileShare, as does the account we used for the search - it is an AD account synchronized to the cloud.
Initially, we suspected that our data was not indexed in the cloud. However, when we crawled a Site Collection to the cloud, we were able to search for it successfully.
Additionally, when we crawled the FileShare using the Default Search Service Application and searched for the documents in on-premises SharePoint, we were able to find them.
Has anyone encountered this issue or have any insights on how to resolve it?

Are the authorisation groups from the file server also synchronised from AD to the cloud? If the groups are not available in MS 365, the SharePiont search service cannot resolve the groups and therefore does not see any authorisations. Without authorisations, nothing will be displayed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I made some progress and can now see files and folders from the File Share located on my on-premises server. Here’s what I did:
On the on-premises server, I went to Computer Management > Shares, opened the properties of the File Share, and navigated to the Security tab. I opened the Advanced options and went to the Permissions tab. The only account present was the one acting as the Content Access Account, with Modify permissions. I changed this to Full Control and added the account used for performing searches in SharePoint Online, setting its permission to Read. After running a full crawl, I was able to search for files and folders from this File Share in SharePoint Online.
I requested the same permissions to be set on the Network File Share. However, even though the security team applied these settings, I still do not get any results after running a full crawl on it. One potential reason could be that the security team did not set the permissions as requested. I will need to call them to confirm this.
